# Why mysql select count(distinct user_id) return wrong number？

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a big table in mysql.It has 13 million rows.

Mysql version is 5.7.10.

Table structure as below:

```
create table table_name (    
  user_id varchar(20) not null,    
  item_id varchar(20) not null 
);
```

**1. The first sql is:**

```
select count(distinct user_id) from table;
```

*result:760,000*

**2. The second sql is:**

```
select count(1) from (select user_id from table group by user_id) a;
```

*result:120,000*

**user_id is not null** for each row.

And, the right number is 120,000.Why the first sql get the wrong number?

Then,I run the first sql in hive and spark-sql, the result is 120,000.

So, is this a mysql's bug or something can be setting to make things right?

Thank you!

**Update**:I try it on another PC, the result of first sql is 120,000.This time get the right number.Mysql version is 5.6.26.
So, maybe it is a bug of 5.7.10.

Comment: There have been 1-2 of these bugs in the past [e.g. this one](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70038). Perhaps another instance of a similar bug and/or a regression?

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB??

Comment: Both of them I have try. At first,It is InnoDB, then I change to MyISAM.The result of the first sql is always wrong .

Comment: Can you update question with adding structure of table ?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Done!  Table Structure is very simple,just two columns,user_id and item_id.

Comment: @Mr.Zhang : well, it maybe due to wrong data type. user_id or item_id because these are keys so these type should be int (11)

Comment: ....drop it...(my mistake), sorry

Comment: I don't really know about MySQL but, could it be a dirty read?

Answer (score 2):

There **are** multiple known bugs in MySQL count distinct when a column is included in two-column unique key.

[here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70038) and [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69841)